# Load image in UserForm from same path as the VBA macro file

Tags: vba, solidworks

I would like to keep some images in the same directory as my macro file and then load them into my UserForm.  This is for a SolidWorks macro, if that matters.  The image loads if I put the full path, but this macro will be deployed onto several workstations, so a path relative to the SWP/macro file is desired.

Couldn't be this lucky:

```
Private Sub RENTRY_Click()
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(".\IMAGE.bmp", 552, 358, Default)
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub RENTRY_Click()
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("IMAGE.bmp", 552, 358, Default)
End Sub
```

Comment: Path relative to what exactly?

Comment: Path relative to the .SWP (macro) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetCurrentMacroPathFolder` to find the path to the currrently-executing macro file

```
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim pathname As String

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
pathname = swApp.GetCurrentMacroPathFolder
```